# How to make links in line

Tags: php, html, css

I take data `$number` from a table and then print it :

```
echo "<div class='pagination'><a href='page_pagination.php?number=". $number ."' >  ". $number ." </a></div>";
```

But. it doesn't printedt in one line, I've tried this using display inline :

```
.pagination {
    display: inline;
}
```

but it still does not work too. How to make them in one line ? thank you :)
var_dump($number) :

```
string(1) "2"
      2
string(1) "3"
      3
etc..
```

the complete :

```
<div id="page">
<?php
     $query2 = mysql_query(" .....");
     while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
         ....
         echo '<div id="content">';
         echo '<div class="post">';
         ...
         echo '<div class="entry">';
         ...
     }
     echo '</div>';
     echo '</div>';
     $query3 = mysql_query(" ..... ");
     while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)) {
         ...
         echo "<span class='pagination'><a href='page_pagination.php?number=". $number ."' >  ". $number ."    </a></span>";
     }
     echo '</div>';
?>
</div>
```

css :

```
#page {
   width: 980px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0px 220px 0px 0px;
   border-top: 1px solid #b4c1a1;
   background: #ffffff ;
}

#content {
  width: 780px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
   background: url(images/img04.gif) no-repeat bottom;
}

.post {
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.post .entry {
   padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   text-align: justify;
}
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<center><div id="pagination"><span><a href='page_pagination.php?number=2' >  2 </a></div>
<center><div id="pagination"><span><a href='page_pagination.php?number=3' >  3 </a></div>
<center><div id="pagination"><span><a href='page_pagination.php?number=4' >  4 </a></div>
<center><div id="pagination"><span><a href='page_pagination.php?number=5' >  5 </a></div>
<center><div id="pagination"><span><a href='page_pagination.php?number=6' >  6 </a></div>
<center><div id="pagination"><span><a href='page_pagination.php?number=7' >  7 </a></div>
<center><div id="pagination"><span><a href='page_pagination.php?number=8' >  8 </a></div>
<center><div id="pagination"><span><a href='page_pagination.php?number=9' >  9 </a></div>
<center><div id="pagination"><span><a href='page_pagination.php?number=Next' >  Next </a></div>
```

here's the link that show the rendered output = http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=fferP

Comment: `var_dump($number)` .. what can you see

Comment: do you know what is `float: left`? if not try it :)

Comment: The code you posted is perfect, it should be displayed inline. There must be some other problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @Baba I've added the result of `var_dump($number) ` in my question :)

Comment: @Reflective i've tried it, still does not work

Comment: I hope you don't have `display:none` somewhere in your `CSS`

Comment: @AbhiBeckert yes, I think so. is it because i take from the database will affect it?

Comment: can we have a complete example?

Comment: @Reflective I've edded in my question :)

Comment: Post your rendered output (HTML) too.

Comment: @rosen, what you've added works fine ... you have some other problem, priatelu ;) show me your page if it is online and for just 1 min i'll tell you where is your probelm ... unfortunately Vanga is death and no one of us have extrasensuel knowledge :)

Comment: @Sparky672 how to rendered the output ?

Comment: Go to browser, show source code, copy & paste.

Comment: @Sparky672 go to this link : http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=uGOwc

Comment: You clearly did not use my code as posted!  Now you have `<span>`'s wrapped in `div`'s and not even done as valid HTML.  Where is the closing `</span>`?  Also, you should be posting this code inside the question where it's more useful than a link in a comment.

Comment: @Sparky672 I've tried your code, sir. but then I changed it again. I returned to use your code. http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=fferP and will do sir, I will post the link in my question..

Comment: Just pay attention to the format of your rendered output.  Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @Sparky672 what do you mean with invalid? in which part ?

Comment: `<center>` and `<span>` both require their respective closing tags, `</center>` and `</span>`; that's basic HTML and should be obvious.  Also, `<center></center>` was deprecated long ago.  See the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: @Sparky672 yes, I got it ! thank you so much sir ! :) the problem is there are 2 unused `</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<center>` tags (which are not present in you snippet of PHP code but present in the “Rendered HTML” and at the “rendered output”, so you are generating them somehow).

The `<center>` element is a block level element, so it causes its content to appear on a line of its own.

The `<center>` element is deprecated too, but that’s not the point here. The point is that if each number is in a `<center>` elements of its own, you get the problem described.

You could modify the code so that there’s just one `<center>` before the list and one `</center>` after it. But it’s better and simpler to remove all `<center>` tags and then considered whether you want the list centered; if you do, wrap the the list e.g. between `<div class=pages>` and `</div>` and add `.pages { text-align: center; }` into your style sheet.

Comment: yes. that's right. I've removed <center> tag too before. thanks for the explanation, sir. I learn something :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it inline, then why are you wrapping it in a `div`?

Just use `span` instead, which is `inline` by default.

```
echo "<span class='pagination'><a href='page_pagination.php?number=". $number ."' >  ". $number ." </a></span>";
```

CSS:

```
.pagination {
    /* nothing to do here because <span> is already inline */
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a div. Sometimes you don't know, when designing the HTML, whether something needs to be inline or not. The CSS can control it. Also, there are some tags that can be inside a `<div>` but are not allowed to be inside a `<span>` tag (this would be more applicable to `display: inline-block;` than `display: inline;` of course).

Comment: @AbhiBeckert:  I did not say it was wrong... but it's certainly verbose.  If you want something to be `inline`, then using `div` and forcing it to behave differently than its default would not be my first choice.

Comment: I agree with @Sparky672, however the correct semantic choice here would seem to be `<li>` tags (inside a `<ol>`) being the links related to each other and being the ordering, important (pagination links!)

Comment: @Luca, while I also use `<ol>` and `<ul>` for various inline navigational elements, I'm not so sure we can call that semantically correct either.  After all, `ol` and `ul` are vertical lists and CSS is required to alter their default behavior to force `inline`.

Comment: @rosen_: None of this is making sense.  `span` is an inline element.  You should also post your ***rendered*** HTML so we can see what might be causing this.

Comment: @Sparky672 presentation doesn't relate to content though; block and inline are simply presentation values, while semantics should relate to content only (IMHO!)

Answer (score 0):

The first while cycle opens as many `<div>` tags `x3` as the items of the cycle, but they are closed once ... after the cycle ...so if your code is correctly represented, you will have a completely messed HTML.

```
<div id="page">
<?php
     $query2 = mysql_query(" .....");
     while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
         ....
         echo '<div id="content">';
         echo '<div class="post">';
         echo '<div class="entry">';

         ...

         echo '</div>';
         echo '</div>';
         echo '</div>';


     }
     $query3 = mysql_query(" ..... ");
     echo "<div>"; 
     while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)) {
         ...
         echo "<a href='page_pagination.php?number=". $number ."' >  ". $number ."    </a>";
     }
     echo "</div>"; 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course if the OP would only post his rendered output, we'd know this for sure.